# Store a JSON string in C# and then access individual parts of it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am pulling some JSON from an API. It comes in this format:

```
{"yourname": {
"id": 42728521,
"name": "Your Name",
"profileIconId": 27,
"revisionDate": 1397930999000,
"summonerLevel": 1
}}
```

However, that is stored as:

```
"{\"yourname\":{\"id\":42728521,\"name\":\"Your Name\",\"profileIconId\":27,\"summonerLevel\":1,\"revisionDate\":1397930999000}}"
```

Inside the string.

I want to be able to call summonerLevel and for it to return the correct value.

I've been trying this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            api_return = client.DownloadString(api_call_key);
        }

 var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summoner>(api_return);

        Console.WriteLine(Summoner.id);
        Console.WriteLine(Summoner.name);
        Console.WriteLine(Summoner.summonerLevel);

        string id_ = foo.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(id_);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public class Summoner
    {
        public static int id { get; set; }
        public static string name { get; set; }
        public static int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

However, that just prints out:

0
nothing
0

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Comment: You're storing the deserialized object inside your  `foo` variable, use it to access the values.

Comment: Apparantly I'm not storing them in the foo variable http://i.gyazo.com/28b9d4c00455784bfcd066f522397015.png

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here, which are both preventing you from getting the data from the JSON.

The first issue is that the properties of your `Summoner` class should not be `static`, as Vikas pointed out.  Define your class like this:

```
public class Summoner
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

The second issue is that your JSON structure doesn't match what you're deserializing into.  The `id`, `name` and `summonerLevel` properties are not at the root level of the JSON, they are one level further down, inside another object.  So, you'll need to deserialize into some class that "wraps" your `Summoner`.  If the `yourname` property in the JSON were a fixed value, you could define a Wrapper class like this to deserialize into:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("yourname")]
    public Summoner Summoner { get; set; }
}
```

However, since the `yourname` property in the JSON is likely not a fixed value (it could change for different summoners), I would recommend deserializing into a `Dictionary<string, Summoner>` like this instead:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Summoner>>(json);
```

From there, you can either loop through the dictionary key-value pairs, or, if you're only expecting one, you can use `First()` to get it.

```
var summoner = dict.First().Value;
```

Here is a full demo:

```
string json = @"{""yourname"": {
                ""id"": 42728521,
                ""name"": ""Your Name"",
                ""profileIconId"": 27,
                ""revisionDate"": 1397930999000,
                ""summonerLevel"": 1
                }}";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Summoner>>(json);
var summoner = dict.First().Value;

Console.WriteLine(summoner.id);
Console.WriteLine(summoner.name);
Console.WriteLine(summoner.summonerLevel);
```

Output:

```
42728521
Your Name
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties in `Summoner` class should not be `static`

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    api_return = client.DownloadString(api_call_key);
}

var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summoner>(api_return);

Console.WriteLine(foo.id);
Console.WriteLine(foo.name);
Console.WriteLine(foo.summonerLevel);

..............

}

public class Summoner
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This prints out
0
blank
0

Comment: Decorate the properties with `JsonProperty` attribute.